# Windows 8 restart every day at 12:13:14 AM

Tags: windows-8, virus, reboot

I assume it's a virus, but I couldn't find about it on the web. My windows started to (I don't know what I did, or which program I've installed) restart every day at 12:13:14 AM. I have no idea what causes it. It has began one day. I couldn't find a task in the task scheduler that triggers at that particular time.
thanks in advance

Comment: Does it happen in safe mode, update question, with the answer

Comment: Anything in the event log?

Comment: thank you for your replies, never checked in safe mode, I have solved it - it was the sql server agent that causes the restarts. I've disabled it from services and the problem stoped

Answer (score 0):

Check The `Event Viewer` of Windows.

`Windows Logs > System`

This can help you guessing which application causes restart. Something like:

```
The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe (PCNAME-PC) has initiated the restart of computer PCNAME-PC on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x800000ff
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment:
```